# MATLAB mex linking error using clang and external library fftw3

Tags: matlab, linker, clang, mex, fftw

My question is about linking errors I get when compiling with external libraries using mex. I'm trying to compile C++ code using the external library fftw3 using Matlab's mex on MacOS using clang++. Here is an example

## main.cpp

```cpp
#include "fftw3.h"

int main(){
  double * test = (double *) fftw_malloc(10*sizeof(double));
}
```

compiling this works

```cpp
$ clang++ main.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -lfftw3
```

Now I try something similar with mex

## mex.cpp

```cpp
#include "math.h"
#include "matrix.h"
#include "mex.h"
#include "fftw3.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
  double * test = (double *) fftw_malloc(10*sizeof(double));
}
```

### in MATLAB

```cpp
>> mex -setup C++;
>> mex -L/usr/local/lib -lfftw3 CXXFLAGS='-L/usr/local/lib -lfftw3' mex.cpp
Building with 'Xcode Clang++'.
Error using mex
clang: warning: -lfftw3: 'linker' input unused
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-L/usr/local/lib'
/path/to/file/mex.cpp:4:10:
fatal error: 'fftw3.h' file not found
#include "fftw3.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
```

using the `-v` flag I get more detailed errors

```cpp
Verbose mode is on.
Neither -compatibleArrayDims nor -largeArrayDims is selected.
     Using -compatibleArrayDims. In the future, MATLAB will require the use of
     -largeArrayDims and remove the -compatibleArrayDims option.
     For more information:
     http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/upgrading-mex-files-to-use-64-bit-api.html.

... Looking for compiler 'Xcode Clang++' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'DEVELOPER_DIR' ...No.
... Executing command 'xcode-select -print-path' ...Yes ('/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer').
... Looking for folder '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer' ...Yes.
... Executing command 'which xcrun' ...Yes ('/usr/bin/xcrun').
... Looking for folder '/usr/bin' ...Yes.
... Executing command 'defaults read com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEXcodeVersionForAgreedToGMLicense' ...No.
... Executing command 'defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEXcodeVersionForAgreedToGMLicense' ...Yes ('7.1.1').
... Executing command '
agreed=7.1.1 
 if echo $agreed | grep -E '[\.\"]' >/dev/null; then 
 lhs=`expr "$agreed" : '\([0-9]*\)[\.].*'` 
  rhs=`expr "$agreed" : '[0-9]*[\.]\(.*\)$'` 
 if echo $rhs | grep -E '[\."]' >/dev/null; then 
 rhs=`expr "$rhs" : '\([0-9]*\)[\.].*'` 
 fi 
 if [ $lhs -gt 4 ] || ( [ $lhs -eq 4 ] && [ $rhs -ge 3 ] ); then 
 echo $agreed 
 else 
 exit 1
 fi 
 fi' ...Yes ('7.1.1').
... Executing command 'xcode-select -print-path' ...Yes ('/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer').
... Looking for folder '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk' ...No.
... Looking for folder '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk' ...No.
... Looking for folder '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk' ...Yes.
... Executing command 'xcode-select -print-path' ...Yes ('/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer').
... Looking for folder '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk' ...No.
... Looking for folder '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk' ...No.
... Looking for folder '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk' ...Yes.
... Executing command 'echo /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk | rev | cut -c1-10 | rev | egrep -oh '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+'' ...Yes ('10.11').
Found installed compiler 'Xcode Clang++'.
Options file details
-------------------------------------------------------------------
    Compiler location: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    Options file: ~/.matlab/R2014b/mex_C++_maci64.xml
    CMDLINE100 : /usr/bin/xcrun -sdk macosx10.11 clang++ -c -DMX_COMPAT_32   -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -I"/Applications/MATLAB_R2014b.app/extern/include" -I"/Applications/MATLAB_R2014b.app/simulink/include" -L/usr/local/lib -lfftw3 -O2 -DNDEBUG /path/to/file/mex.cpp -o /var/folders/09/dysbhb1d5zn98sq8lzkwpn5r0000gn/T//mex_291104578803706_45753/mex.o
    CMDLINE200 : /usr/bin/xcrun -sdk macosx10.11 clang++ -Wl,-twolevel_namespace -undefined error -arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.11 -Wl,-syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -framework Cocoa -bundle  -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,"/Applications/MATLAB_R2014b.app/extern/lib/maci64/mexFunction.map" -O -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,"/Applications/MATLAB_R2014b.app/extern/lib/maci64/mexFunction.map" /var/folders/09/dysbhb1d5zn98sq8lzkwpn5r0000gn/T//mex_291104578803706_45753/mex.o   -lfftw3   -L/usr/local/lib   -L"/Applications/MATLAB_R2014b.app/bin/maci64" -lmx -lmex -lmat -o mex.mexmaci64
    CMDLINE300 : rm -f /var/folders/09/dysbhb1d5zn98sq8lzkwpn5r0000gn/T//mex_291104578803706_45753/mex.o
    CXX : /usr/bin/xcrun -sdk macosx10.11 clang++
    DEFINES : -DMX_COMPAT_32   -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE 
    MATLABMEX : -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE 
    CXXFLAGS : -L/usr/local/lib -lfftw3
    INCLUDE : -I"/Applications/MATLAB_R2014b.app/extern/include" -I"/Applications/MATLAB_R2014b.app/simulink/include"
    CXXOPTIMFLAGS : -O2 -DNDEBUG
    CXXDEBUGFLAGS : -g
    LDXX : /usr/bin/xcrun -sdk macosx10.11 clang++
    LDFLAGS : -Wl,-twolevel_namespace -undefined error -arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.11 -Wl,-syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -framework Cocoa -bundle  -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,"/Applications/MATLAB_R2014b.app/extern/lib/maci64/mexFunction.map"
    LDBUNDLE : -bundle 
    LINKEXPORT : -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,"/Applications/MATLAB_R2014b.app/extern/lib/maci64/mexFunction.map"
    LINKLIBS : -lfftw3   -L/usr/local/lib   -L"/Applications/MATLAB_R2014b.app/bin/maci64" -lmx -lmex -lmat
    LDOPTIMFLAGS : -O
    LDDEBUGFLAGS : -g
    OBJEXT : .o
    LDEXT : .mexmaci64
    DEVELOPER_DIR_CHECK : 
    XCODE_DIR : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    XCRUN_DIR : /usr/bin
    XCODE_AGREED_VERSION : 7.1.1
    ISYSROOT : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk
    SDKVER : 10.11
    MATLABROOT : /Applications/MATLAB_R2014b.app
    ARCH : maci64
    SRC : /path/to/file/mex.cpp
    OBJ : /var/folders/09/dysbhb1d5zn98sq8lzkwpn5r0000gn/T//mex_291104578803706_45753/mex.o
    OBJS : /var/folders/09/dysbhb1d5zn98sq8lzkwpn5r0000gn/T//mex_291104578803706_45753/mex.o 
    SRCROOT : /path/to/file/mex
    DEF : /var/folders/09/dysbhb1d5zn98sq8lzkwpn5r0000gn/T//mex_291104578803706_45753/mex.def
    EXP : mex.exp
    LIB : mex.lib
    EXE : mex.mexmaci64
    ILK : mex.ilk
    MANIFEST : mex.mexmaci64.manifest
    TEMPNAME : mex
    EXEDIR : 
    EXENAME : mex
    OPTIM : -O2 -DNDEBUG
    LINKOPTIM : -O
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Building with 'Xcode Clang++'.
/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk macosx10.11 clang++ -c -DMX_COMPAT_32   -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -I"/Applications/MATLAB_R2014b.app/extern/include" -I"/Applications/MATLAB_R2014b.app/simulink/include" -L/usr/local/lib -lfftw3 -O2 -DNDEBUG /path/to/file/mex.cpp -o /var/folders/09/dysbhb1d5zn98sq8lzkwpn5r0000gn/T//mex_291104578803706_45753/mex.o
Error using mex
clang: warning: -lfftw3: 'linker' input unused
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-L/usr/local/lib'
/path/to/file/mex.cpp:4:10:
fatal error: 'fftw3.h' file not found
#include "fftw3.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warnings

```
clang: warning: -lfftw3: 'linker' input unused
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-L/usr/local/lib'
```

are there because you are setting `CXXFLAGS` to contain these flags. This variable is for compiler flags, but `-L` and `-l` are linker flags. Simply remove the `CXXFLAGS` definition from your `mex` command.

The error

```
/path/to/file/mex.cpp:4:10:
fatal error: 'fftw3.h' file not found
#include "fftw3.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
```

is because the compiler cannot find the `fftw4.h` header file. You need to tell the compiler where to find it:

```
mex -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lfftw3 mex.cpp
```

Note that in your first case, where you call `clang++` directly, it is likely that CLang is configured to look for header files in `/usr/local/include`, it's a standard place. But when `mex` invokes your compiler (I don't even know if it's the same one?) apparently this location is not added to the search path.

Comment: I see, I just figured this out, too. Thanks very much for the detailed answer, didn't understand why it worked with clan++ directly!